# how to find spring jdbctemplate batchupdate is successful

Tags: spring, spring-data

```
String[] sql={"insert into customer(name,age) values('v1',21)",
      "insert into customer(name,age) values('v2',22)",
      "insert into customer(name,age) values('v3',23)",
      "insert into customer(name,age) values('v4',24)" };

    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql);
```

How to know whether this batchupdate statement is executed successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Batch update methods return an int array containing the number of affected rows for each statement. I.e in your case you can capture as below.

```
int result[] = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql);
```

So in your,

`result[0]` you get the update count of `insert into customer(name,age) values('v1',21)` query,

`result[1]`  you get the update count of `insert into customer(name,age) values('v2',22)` query and so on.

If there any run time errors you will get [BatchUpdateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/BatchUpdateException.html).

Comment: so 'result[0]' , 'result[1]' . for every thing answer is **1** only

Comment: Since your insert queries are inserting only 1 row, Its expected to receive **1**.

Comment: I believe that result[0] depend on underlying driver. For example postgres implementation will return int number with specific meaning: int SUCCESS_NO_INFO = -2; This is java.sql.Statement class.

Comment: Will batchUpdate rollback if anyone of the statement fails ?